# Horizontal flip animation in Keynote

Tags: keynote

I want to perform a horizontal flip animation between two images in Keynote. How I can do this? The flipping should swipe images

[image: effect]

Answer (score 3):

1. Insert the two images (other object or group to be transitioned).
2. Select the first side and from the animation inspector add a **Build Out** effect of **Flip**. Disable **Bounce**.

   [image]
3. Select the second side and from the animation inspector add a **Build In** effect of **Flip**. Disable **Bounce**.
4. Choose **Build Order** and set the second build (the build in) to **Start: With Build 1**.

   [image]
5. Set the second side to be in front of the first side by right-clicking on the second side and choosing **Bring to Front**. Position the two sides on top of each other.

[image]