# How to change the background colour of the flip transition in Keynote?

Tags: macos, keynote, color, animation

When I try to use transition in Keynote, the slide default color keynote transit to or the slide in the background of transition is always black:

[image]

Can I change this color?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the background colour of the flip transition.

You could create the flip transition yourself by performing the flip build on the entire slide contents: [Horizontal flip animation in Keynote](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/362930/37797).

You can group all elements and build out in one flip, while building in the next slide.

Alternatively, have a separate slide with an image of the current and next slide that you perform the flip on and automatically move to the next slide on completion to hide the effect.

In both cases the slide background colour/image would be used as the background for the flip.